# Calculating number of unique values in column A based on column B

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with the following columns below.

I want to know the number of unique records based on the Product Type. Data should change dynamically by slicing the month.

Based on this logic, there should be:

- 2 records with ABC product type in the month of June,
- 3 records with ABC product type in May and June,
- 1 record with JEJ product type in April,
- 1 record with JEJ product type in ABC in May.

Let's assume there's hundreds of different product types.

Can this be done using PowerBI DAX measure?

| ID | Product Type | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1232323 | ABC | Jun |
| 1223323 | ABC | Jun |
| 1223324 | ABC | May |
| 1223325 | JEJ | Apr |
| 1223325 | JEJ | May |
| 1223344 | ABC | Jun |

I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Check your sample data. There are 3 `ABC` in June, for instance.

Comment: 3 ABC but 2 unique case ID.

Comment: Your statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure:

```
Measure = 
  VAR __Table = SELECTCOLUMNS('Table',"Month",[Month],"Product Type",[Product Type])
RETURN
  COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(__Table))
```

the docs you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dax/selectcolumns-function-dax).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table visual with `Product Type`, add a measure like this:

```
Count = COUNTROWS ( SUMMARIZE ( 'Table' , 'Table'[ID] ) )
```

Add a slicer on the canvas with `Month` and you can interact with the table visual according to your requirements.

Edit: A simplified, and obvious, formula is to just directly do a distinct count:

```
Count = DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[ID] )
```

The evaluation context is given by using a slicer for time, and using the `Product Type` dimension in a visual.

Comment: for date-related analyses, you *really* should have a separate Calendar table with all the columns you want to group by. Makes your job a LOT easier.

Comment: Naturally. But this falls outside the scope of the requirements of OP.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand the DAX measure. How does it calculate ID based on the product type?

Comment: It uses the evaluation context provided in the visual with `Product Type`. I suggest undertaking an introduction course to Power BI if this is not clear - this is the core functionality in Power BI.

Comment: The DAX measure only sums up the number of occurrences. It doesn't really answer my question of how many unique records are there based on the Product Type. 

The measure can be better refined to:

No. of Distinct Occurrence = if (COUNTROWS ( SUMMARIZE ( 'Table' , 'Table'[ID] ) ) =1, 1,0).

However, the row total on the visual will sum up to "0", even though there are values in each row. Would you know the cause?

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood what the measure does, and the context for which it is written (which is stated in my answer). Using this measure in a table visual with the `Product Type` dimension, together with a slicer on month (or year/month for larger datasets), gives the count of unique ID’s per product type for a given selected time period.